# What is the conventional direction of voltage in this circuit?

Tags: diodes

The problem circuit is like this:

[image]

If the diode is conducting, we can replace it with a linear circuit of a generator V_d, and an internal resistance r. Which component comes first after replacing the diode? Looking at the solution, this is the equivalent circuit I don't understand. Which source is supplying the internal resistance?  I can see that both V_e and V_d are supplying it from both sides. Can someone explain to me what the graph of V_s in relation to V_e would look like?

[image]

Comment: "Aliment" means nourishment or food; I think you perhaps mean "supply." I edited accordingly, but please comment if this is incorrect.

Comment: V_d does not supply anything because in this role it is not a source but a load. This is just one way (not the best) to model the diode forward voltage drop by a contrary connected voltage source.

Comment: @JYelton  In some languages the term for power supply can be literally translated as *block of ailment [or nourishment, or feed]*.  Блок питания in Russian.  At the same time, the O.P. draws American-style resistors.  I wonder what's his background and story.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist But doesnt it contribute to the voltage of V_s?

Comment: @NickAlexeev its a french background :d

Comment: @NickAlexeev ailment means illness, aliment means food in most uses, but you will need a technical dictionary to get aliment = supply.

Comment: @NickAlexeev you said it yourself that aliment means nourishment or feed, then im asking if the built-in voltage V_d is feeding or giving electrical resource to the internal resistance

Comment: When forward biased, a diode behaves as (can be replaced with) a constant voltage source V_d that is contrary connected to the input voltage source and having internal resistance "r". So this voltage is subtracted from the input voltage and the current decreases. When backward biased, the diode is "nothing" (open or broken circuit). Both the diode and the resistor introduce a voltage loss (drop), but with the diode it is constant and with the resistor it grows linearly with increasing current.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist but the voltage of the internal resistance is it counted as an increase or decrease to the general voltage? V_e? V_s?

Comment: @HellBoy, The voltage drop across the internal resistance is also a loss that is subtracted from the voltage of the input source. So there is only one true voltage source (the input one) that **produces** power (voltage) and two elements (resistor and diode) that consume power (voltage). We know what a resistor is but imagine we do not know what a diode is. That is why we replace it with a constant voltage source producing 0.7 V opposing voltage and this way we understand what an element it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the conventional direction of voltage in this circuit?

This title does not represent the body text of the question. The arrows in the diagram indicate the polarity (direction??) of the voltage: a) across the open circuit and b) labeled as \$V_s (t)\$, across the series combination of the \$E\$ and the diode. The head (tip) of the arrow is considered more positive than the tail of the arrow.

The circuit is open so there is no current through the resistor or the diode , as shown in Figure 1. So there is 0V across the diode indicating that \$V_s=E\$. There is 0V across the resistor, so \$V_e=V_s\$, therefore \$V_e=E\$ also.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLzkZD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> If the diode is conducting...

In order for the diode to conduct a load must be connected shown as \$R_2\$ in Figure 2. Notice that \$V_e\$ and \$V_s\$ are not sources. They are measured values.

> Which component comes first after replacing the diode?

It does not matter. Components in series can be interchanged if the orientation is maintained.

> Which source is supplying the internal resistance?

You are interpreting the labels \$V_e\$, \$V_d\$ and \$V_s\$ as sources. They are not. They are measured values only. \$E\$ is the **only** source in the circuit. It supplies the entire series circuit.

> I can see that both V_e and V_d are supplying [r_D] from both sides.

**Neither \$V_e\$ or \$V_d\$ are supplying voltage.** Both voltages are a consequence of the charge flowing through the circuit. Again the labels \$V_e\$ and \$V_d\$ are just labels indicating a measured value.

> Can someone explain to me what the graph of V_s in relation to V_e would look like?

1. In the case of the "*unloaded circuit* shown in the original post (my Figure2), the current is zero. So, the graph is based on: $$V_e=V_s$$
2. In the loaded case:$$V_e=V_s-IR_1$$where \$R_1\$ is the 1k resistor.

Notice that:$$V_s=E-V_D-Ir_D$$

Comment: Im infinitely grateful for this explanation , one last confusion, concerning the unload/loaded cases of the diode -its an ideal diode in my problem- what are the conditions on that? like i know the diode is not  conducting when V_d = 0 thus V_s = E, but what about when its conducting?

Comment: I just checked the problem paper, and no they are calling V_e and V_s respectively the input/output voltage meaning its supplying somehow?

Comment: @HellBoy"-its an ideal diode in my problem-" No it isn't. There are two approximations. 1) The forward voltage is a constant 0.7V. 2) a resistor approximates the diode resistance. An ideal diode has zero resistance and 0V across it  when conducting.

Comment: @HellBoy:" i know the diode is not conducting when V_d = 0 thus V_s = E, but what about when its conducting?" To make the diode conduct (loaded conditions) E must be greater than 0.7V. Read my answer.

Comment: @HellBoy: "and no they are calling V_e and V_s respectively the input/output voltage meaning its supplying somehow?". \$E\$,\$V_e\$,and \$V_s\$ are just labels so to give particular voltages a name. E and V are both used to indicate voltage.  E is often used in textbooks to indicate a voltage source that supplies voltage and current. V is often used to indicate a measuered voltage between two nodes. In your diagram both symbols are used . E is beside a voltage source symbol. This is the case in your diagram so E implies a source that can supply voltage and current. /continued

Comment: /continued: V then implies a measured voltage that results from current in your circuit.